# Updating "text" nodes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have html like:

```
<label><input type="radio" /> Lorem</label>
```

What's the best way to change "Lorem" to "Ipsum"? These don't work:

```
// nope:
$('input').next().text('Ipsum'); 

// also nope:
var text = $('input').parent()[0].childNodes[1];
$(text).text('Ipsum');
```

I can easily change the html to:

```
<label><input type="radio" /><span> Lorem</span></label>
```

or use the `replaceWholeText` DOM method directly:

```
$('input').parent()[0].childNodes[1].replaceWholeText(' Ipsum');
```

or any number of other things, but I'm wondering if there's a clean jQuery way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('label').contents().last().replaceWith("Ipsum");`

However, I personally would use `nodeValue`.

Hope this helps!

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/25/

Answer (score 1):

The ugly way:

```
 $('input').parent().contents().each(function(){
   if(this.nodeType === 3)
     this.nodeValue= "Ipsum";
 });
```

Or better:

```
$('input')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "Ipsum";
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have any first class text node support. You could:

```
$("input")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "Ipsum";
```

Or use a `<span>` with an identifier or class and target that. If you need to change the text dynamically it probably warrants a container like that.